# Получить логин в момент присоединения к WCF службе

Tags: c#, .net, windows, wcf

Есть WCF служба, которая работает по TCP.

Как я могу получить логин в момент открытия соединения, а не в момент вызовов методов?

Могу ли я получить имя приложения с которое осуществляется подключение?

Если можно, то с примером.

Answer (score 1):

Нет, не можете. Нет, тоже не можете.

Формат передаваемых сообщений устроен таким образом, что токен безопасности передается только при вызовах методов. Ну а "имя приложения" вообще не существует в рамках WCF.

Конечно, для передачи имени приложения можно воспользоваться [заголовками SOAP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1687192/4340086) - но надо помнить, что такой способ различать приложения является сугубо добровольным, на него нельзя завязывать логику безопасности.